# Rationale of -rpath-link

Tags: gcc, linker, ld

I am using `-rpath-link` with `ld` when creating a shared library that needs some symbols from other shared library that is not in a default place (for example, if I am creating it as part of my build process).

My question is, why isn't the `-L` option allowed to have this functionality? why does `ld` need an extra option to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between \`-rpath-link\` and \`-L\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138195/whats-the-difference-between-rpath-link-and-l)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The other question was about what those two options are. The question here is what's the rationale for having two separate options, and there's not been an answer yet. i.e. what situations would lead to have different values for -L and -rpath-link.