# What's the difference between `-rpath-link` and `-L`?

Tags: linker, ld, gold-linker, bfd, lld

The man for `gold` states:

```
  -L DIR, --library-path DIR
          Add directory to search path

  --rpath-link DIR
          Add DIR to link time shared library search path
```

The man for bfd `ld` makes it sort of sound like `-rpath-link` is used for recursively included sos.

`ld.lld` doesn't even list it as an argument.

Could somebody clarify this situation for me?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Here is a demo, for GNU `ld`, of the difference between `-L` and `-rpath-link` -
and for good measure, the difference between `-rpath-link` and `-rpath`.

**foo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}
```

**bar.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bar(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}
```

**foobar.c**

```
extern void foo(void);
extern void bar(void);

void foobar(void)
{
    foo();
    bar();
}
```

**main.c**

```
extern void foobar(void);

int main(void)
{
    foobar();
    return 0;
}
```

Make two shared libraries, `libfoo.so` and `libbar.so`:

```
$ gcc -c -Wall -fPIC foo.c bar.c
$ gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
$ gcc -shared -o libbar.so bar.o
```

Make a third shared library, `libfoobar.so` that depends on the first two;

```
$ gcc -c -Wall -fPIC foobar.c
$ gcc -shared -o libfoobar.so foobar.o -lfoo -lbar
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfoo
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbar
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Oops. The linker doesn't know where to look to resolve `-lfoo` or `-lbar`.

The `-L` option fixes that.

```
$ gcc -shared -o libfoobar.so foobar.o -L. -lfoo -lbar
```

The `-Ldir` option tells the linker that `dir` is one of the directories to
search for libraries that resolve the `-lname` options it is given. It searches
the `-L` directories first, in their commandline order; then it searches its
configured default directories, in their configured order.

Now make a program that depends on `libfoobar.so`:

```
$ gcc -c -Wall main.c
$ gcc -o prog main.o -L. -lfoobar
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libfoo.so, needed by ./libfoobar.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libbar.so, needed by ./libfoobar.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
./libfoobar.so: undefined reference to `bar'
./libfoobar.so: undefined reference to `foo'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Oops again. The linker detects the dynamic dependencies requested by `libfoobar.so`
but can't satisfy them. Let's resist its advice - `try using -rpath or -rpath-link` -
for a bit and see what we can do with `-L` and `-l`:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o -L. -lfoobar -lfoo -lbar
```

So far so good. But:

```
$ ./prog
./prog: error while loading shared libraries: libfoobar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

at runtime, the loader can't find `libfoobar.so`.

What about the linker's advice then? With `-rpath-link`, we can do:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o -L. -lfoobar -Wl,-rpath-link=$(pwd)
```

and that linkage also succeeds. (`$(pwd)` means "**P**rint **W**orking **D**irectory" and just "copies" the current path.)

The `-rpath-link=dir` option tells the linker that when it encounters an input file that
requests dynamic dependencies - like `libfoobar.so` - it should search directory `dir` to
resolve them. So we *don't need* to specify those dependencies with `-lfoo -lbar` and don't
even need to know what they are. What they are is information already written in the
dynamic section of `libfoobar.so`:-

```
$ readelf -d libfoobar.so

Dynamic section at offset 0xdf8 contains 26 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libfoo.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libbar.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 ...
 ...
```

We just need to know a directory where they can be found, whatever they are.

But does that give us a runnable `prog`?

```
$ ./prog
./prog: error while loading shared libraries: libfoobar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

No. Same as story as before. That's because `-rpath-link=dir` gives the linker the information
that the loader *would need* to resolve some of the dynamic dependencies of `prog`
at runtime - assuming it remained true at runtime - but *it doesn't write that information into the dynamic section of* `prog`.
It just lets the linkage succeed, without our needing to spell out all the recursive dynamic
dependencies of the linkage with `-l` options.

At runtime, `libfoo.so`, `libbar.so` - and indeed `libfoobar.so` -
might well not be where they are now - `$(pwd)` -  but the loader might be able to locate them
by other means: through the [`ldconfig`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig) cache or a setting
of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, e.g:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.; ./prog
foo
bar
```

`rpath=dir` provides the linker with the same information as `rpath-link=dir`
*and* instructs the linker to bake that information into the dynamic section of
the output file. Let's try that:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
$ gcc -o prog main.o -L. -lfoobar -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)
$ ./prog
foo
bar
```

All good. Because now, `prog` contains the information that `$(pwd)` is a runtime search
path for shared libraries that it depends on, as we can see:

```
$ readelf -d prog

Dynamic section at offset 0xe08 contains 26 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libfoobar.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [/home/imk/develop/so/scrap]
 ...                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 ...
```

That search path will be tried after the directories listed in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, if any are set, and before the system defaults - the `ldconfig`-ed directories, plus `/lib` and `/usr/lib`.

Comment: This is a great answer, let me just add to this that in 'modern' versions of GCC will use RUNPATH. Only older compilers have RPATH by default. RUNPATH does not make dependencies inherit the search path, it only applies to the search path of the current binary. In the example above: `libfoobar.so` will be found at runtime, but `libfoo.so` and `libbar.so` won't. You will have to specify the `-Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)` for `libfoobar.so` too :) or you have to do `-Wl,--disable-new-dtags` to get RPATHS, and then the Mike's example is still valid.

Comment: What is still unclear to me: why not let dynamic dependencies also look in the path provided by -L? Or alternatively, why not search for libraries in the path specified by -rpath-link? What is the rationale that both -L and -rpath-link exist?

Comment: ./prog 
./prog: error while loading shared libraries: libfoo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I still need add rpath to libfoobar.so to let if find libfoo.so and libbar.so at runtime. gcc -shared -o libfoobar.so foobar.o -L. -lfoo -lbar -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)

Answer (score 11):

The `--rpath-link` option is used by bfd ld to add to the search path used for finding DT_NEEDED shared libraries when doing link-time symbol resolution. It's basically telling the linker what to use as the runtime search path when attempting to mimic what the dynamic linker would do when resolving symbols (as set by `--rpath` options or the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable).

Gold does not follow DT_NEEDED entries when resolving symbols in shared libraries, so the `--rpath-link` option is ignored. This was a deliberate design decision; indirect dependencies do not need to be present or in their runtime locations during the link process.

Comment: Thanks!  We were getting linker errors and lots of "try using -rpath or -rpath-link" and it turned out that we had accidentally switched from gold to bfd.