# On linking of shared libraries, are they really final, and if so, why?

Tags: linker, compiler-construction, shared-libraries, dynamic-library

I am trying to understand more about linking and shared library.

Ultimately, I wonder if it's possible to add a method to a shared library. For instance, suppose one has a source file a.c, and a library lib.so (without the source file). Let's furthermore assume, for simplicity, that a.c declares a single method, whose name is not present in lib.so. I thought maybe it might be possible to, at linking time, link a.o to lib.so while instructing to create newLib.so, and forcing the linker to export all methods/variable in lib.so to that the newLib.so is now basically lib.so with the added method from a.so.

More generally, if one has some source file depending on a shared library, can one create a single output file (library or executable) that is not dependent on the shared library anymore ? (That is, all the relevant methods/variable from the library would have been exported/linked/inlined to the new executable, hence making the dependency void). If that's not possible, what is technically preventing it ?

A somehow similar question has been asked here: [Merge multiple .so shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915128/merge-multiple-so-shared-libraries).
One of the reply includes the following text: "If you have access to either source or object files for both libraries, it is straightforward to compile/link a combined SO from them.: without explaining the technical details. Was it a mistake or does it hold ? If so, how to do it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you have a shared library `libfoo.so` the only ways you can use it
in the linkage of anything else are:-

Link a program that dynamically depends on it, e.g.

```
$ gcc -o prog bar.o ... -lfoo
```

Or, link another shared library that dynamically depends on it, e.g.

```
$ gcc -shared -o libbar.so bar.o ... -lfoo
```

In either case the product of the linkage, `prog` or `libbar.so`
acquires a dynamic dependency on `libfoo.so`. This means that `prog|libfoo.so`
has information inscribed in it by the linker that instructs the
OS loader, at runtime, to find `libfoo.so`, load it into the
address space of the current process and bind the program's references to `libfoo`'s exported symbols to
the addresses of their definitions.

So `libfoo.so` must continue to exist as well as `prog|libbar.so`.
It is not possible to link `libfoo.so` with `prog|libbar.so` in
such a way that `libfoo.so` is physically merged into `prog|libbar.so`
and is no longer a runtime dependency.

It doesn't matter whether or not you have the source code of the
other linkage input files - `bar.o ...` - that depend on `libfoo.so`. The
only kind of linkage you can do with a shared library is dynamic linkage.

This is in complete contrast with the linkage of a [static library](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-libraries/info)

You wonder about the statement in this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/915181/1362568) where it says:

> If you have access to either source or object files for both libraries, it is straightforward to compile/link a combined SO from them.

The author is just observing that if I have source files

```
foo_a.c foo_b.c... bar_a.c bar_b.c
```

which I compile to the corresponding object files:

```
foo_a.o foo_b.o... bar_a.o bar_b.o...
```

*or* if I simply have those object files. Then as well as - or instead of - linking them into two shared libraries:

```
$ gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo_a.o foo_b.o...
$ gcc -shared -o libbar.so bar_a.o bar_b.o...
```

I could link them into one:

```
$ gcc -shared -o libfoobar.so foo_a.o foo_b.o... bar_a.o bar_b.o...
```

which would have no dependency on `libfoo.so` or `libbar.so` even if they exist.

And although that *could* be straightforward it could also be false. If there is
any symbol `name` that is globally defined in any of `foo_a.o foo_b.o...` and
also globally defined in any of `bar_a.o bar_b.o...` then it will not matter
to  the linkage of either `libfoo.so` or `libbar.so` (and it need not be dynamically
exported by either of them). But the linkage of `libfoobar.so` will fail for
multiple definition of `name`.

If we build a shared library `libbar.so` that depends on `libfoo.so` and has
itself been *linked* with `libfoo.so`:

```
$ gcc -shared -o libbar.so bar.o ... -lfoo
```

and we then want to link a program with `libbar.so`, we can do that in such a way
that we don't need to *mention* its dependency `libfoo.so`:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o ... -lbar -Wl,-rpath=<path/to/libfoo.so>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49181161/1362568) to follow that up. But
this doesn't change the fact that `libbar.so` has a runtime dependency on `libfoo.so`.

> If that's not possible, what is technically preventing it?

What technically prevents linking a shared library with some program
or shared library `targ` in a way that physically merges it into `targ` is that a
shared library (like a program) is not the sort of thing that a linker knows
how to physically merge into its output file.

Input files that the linker can physically merge into `targ` need to
have structural properties that guide the linker in doing that merging. That is the structure of *object files*.
They consist of named *input sections* of object code or data that are tagged with various attributes.
Roughly speaking, the linker cuts up the object files into their sections and distributes them into
*output sections* of the output file according to their attributes, and makes
binary modifications to the merged result to resolve static symbol references
or enable the OS loader to resolve dynamic ones at runtime.

This is not a reversible process. The linker can't consume a program or
shared library and reconstruct the object files from which it was made to
merge them again into something else.

But that's really beside the point. When input files are physically
merged into `targ`, that is called *static* linkage.
When input files are just *externally referenced* in `targ` to
make the OS loader map them into a process it has launched for `targ`,
that is called *dynamic* linkage. Technical development has given us
a file-format solution to each of these needs: object files for static linkage, shared libraries
for dynamic linkage. Neither can be used for the purpose of the other.